# How do I enable editing and deleting rows from a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is it possible to both edit and delete a table row after you enter editing mode on the TableView? I have figured out how to do the delete one seperately. Using the standard editing button and then delete.

But I would like it to be so that I can press the edit button, and it gives me the option per row to delete or edit. Like the way it works in the Clock > Alarm on your iphone. Both options are activated through the edit button, but I don't quite see how.

I have looked on google, and stackoverflow but I cannot find a solution to this. If there are any examples out there or tutorials that you know of (and I did not find) please do share them.

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphone-DeleteandaddrowfromTableView.html http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/29/iphone-sdk-tutorial-add-delete-reorder-uitableview-row/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to change your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. Do a check if the `[self.table isEditing]` and if it is editing you change what your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method does.